# How to Debug Internal working of Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to know is there any way I could debug and understand the Internal working of Rails ActiveRecord , ActiveController  , Request and Response working , dispatching  etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find surprisingly few reasons to use any kind of IDE with Ruby, but debugging into the Rails framework, either out of curiosity, a need to fix some misunderstanding on my part or to identify a bug (I only found one and it was tiny) is the main one.

There's good list here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826164/a-definitive-list-of-ides-for-ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826164) ; personally I find NetBeans adequate. And the price is right.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the best way is to read the code and use a debugger like [ruby-debug](http://rubyforge.org/projects/ruby-debug/). Checkout this [tutorial on ruby-debug](http://ireneros.com/ruby-debug-to-the-rescue). One last resource: Jamis Buck has a pretty nice series on his blog about [Rails under the hood](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/under-the-hood).

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't getting a book like [AGWDR](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/rails2/agile-web-development-with-rails) and the [Rails API Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) be a shorter route than a step-through debugger ?
Update: I was going to say that I've never seen a step-thru debugger for ruby.. but Mark already posted one :) Rubyists at work. However it still feels like a painful approach to learning.